# Accelerate of IOS Spectral Flux detection function

Tags: ios, audio, fft, core-audio

I'm working on a IOS function for audio spectral flux signal for a peak finder. 
It is used to obtain an array of flux to feed a peak detector.

But i'm facing a issue, it is slow.

iPad mini : Finished in : 30.943131 sec(s) for 6.226721 min(s)

iPad air : Finished in : 7.547086 sec(s) for 6.226721 min(s)

iPhone 5 : Finished in : 18.188398 sec(s) for 6.226721 min(s)

**EDIT New stats**:

iPad mini : Finished in : 22.382947 for 6.226721 min(s) 29% gain

iPad air : Finished in : 3.890087 for 6.226721 min(s) 48% gain

iPhone 5 : Finished in : 12.774067 for 6.226721 min(s) 33% gain

So, I tried during a lot of times to accelerate the function, but I didn't find a true solution.
But I'm still convincing that something can be done.

So now I'm looking for some helps to accelerate the process because I pretty sure, I missed something and it can be faster.

Very important!

The HopeTime (Spacing of audio frames) has to stay at 0,010 Ms for the best scan result, and I can't drop my framecount (Total number of audio frames) as well to keep the flux quite good.

So for example :

I tried to raise the fftSize buffer and the buffSize and adapt the last loop for the flux to keep it intact, but with 2048 it's perfect but when I use 4096 each time I got a crash from the FFT accelerate function?

I tried also to get directly the stream in mono from the reader to reduce the amount of data but the reader seems to mix the channel left with the rigth and at the end the result is deteriorated.

the function is here : https://github.com/ppeau/IOS-SpectralFlux and It's very simple, It's just a class.

With the small wav file there is a test function to verify the values of the flux, but not with the long one (too many data).

By the way can be a good example and informations for reader audio files or manipulate pcm data.

Thanks

Comment: You should profile the code in Instruments and see if there are any obvious hot spots that might be worth focussing your optimisation efforts on.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I don't know if profiling can change something in this case but I gonna try, it can be interesting. In audio processing, the hot spots are always at the same place: 1) audio stream and 2) dsp functions, and in this one we have just 3: windowing, FFT, magnitude and at the end a small loop to store the flux. I think, the main issue right here, it is the small amount of samples that I handle in one shot, but when I try to raise it up the values are damaging.

Comment: Try and sample for around 10s if you can, using a 1 ms sample interval.